# Twitter completionHandler freezes app on success

Tags: ios, twitter, ios5

After a completed tweet from `TWTweetComposeViewController`, my app locks up. Going out to the home screen and coming back seems to fix this, and the clock still ticks, but no touches register to any of my views/controls.

Thinking something weird must be happening in my app, I made a fresh utility-app-template project, linked it w/ `Twitter.framework`, and redefined the info `UIButton`'s `IBAction` method to this:

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender
{   
    TWTweetComposeViewController *twt = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [twt setInitialText:@"some garbage"];
    [twt addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
    twt.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult r) { NSLog(@"it happened: %d",r); };
    [self presentViewController:twt animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [twt release];
}
```

After canceling (which takes 2 taps, interestingly), it can be brought back up by tapping the 'i', but after submitting, the 'i' is non-responsive until backgrounding the app.

Has anyone used this successfully? Or am I blatantly missing something?

Comment: I have been seeing the exact same thing (even with the same behavior with the cancel button). The issue goes away if I do not use a completion handler block. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to figure out a way to use the completion block without hanging the app... Interested to hear if anyone has found out why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: how do you use the twitter controller without the completion block?

Comment: This Question is sort of a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703389/twtweetcomposeviewcontroller-not-dismissing-on-ipad-simulator

Comment: This is still true with the iOS6 Twitter implementation of an SLComposeViewController.

Comment: Heads up, registered developers: take a close look at the beta 2 release notes for iOS 7 ('Social' section)...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem here is that you are presenting a modal view controller (the twitter view controller is modal); however, your completion handler isn't dismissing the modal view controller when finished.  This leaves the twitter controller to capture all the touches on the screen preventing your app from functioning properly.

You need to make sure you add [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; to your completion handler.

Something like this:

```
(IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender 
{   
    TWTweetComposeViewController *twt = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [twt setInitialText:@"some garbage"];
    [twt addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
    twt.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) { 
      switch (result) {
        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:                    
           break;

        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
           break;

        default:
           break;
      }
      [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    };

    [self presentModalViewController:twt animated:YES];
```

};

Comment: Also, there are no guarantees about which thread the completion handler will run on, so if you're working with UIKit (and you are if you are dismissing a modal view controller) you **must** use dispatch_async to ensure that the dismissal is performed on the main thread.

Comment: Ahhhh... it was my understanding that it was being dismissed on its own upon cancel/success (since the UI will disappear, leaving behind the phantom tap-capturer). Apparently, that is only the case _without_ a completionHandler. Looking forward to testing this.

Comment: Success! Seems obvious now that I know. Wouldn't have thought to do this. Does any documentation point to this behavior? (curious whether I just missed it somewhere)

Comment: This Question is also sort of a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703389/twtweetcomposeviewcontroller-not-dismissing-on-ipad-simulator

Answer (score 0):

In your `completionHandler`, release `twt`.

```
twt.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult r) {
    NSLog(@"it happened: %d",r);
    [twt release]; // Unless using ARC
};
```

The app doesn't freeze, but the TWTweetComposeView is simply still there, catching all the touches.

Comment: your recommendation is not possible. The twt = nil statement bombs in the compiler with "Variable is not assignable