# TWTweetComposeViewController not dismissing on iPad simulator

Tags: ios5, twitter, modalviewcontroller

In my app I have an action sheet and one of its buttons opens the TWTweetComposeViewController modally. On iPhone simulator the cancel button on the tweet composer works fine and dismisses the view. However, on iPad simulator the cancel button does not work and the tweet composer view remains on the screen. It is even weirder because after pressing the cancel button, the keyboard retracts and the underlying views become active. It behaves as if the view has been dismissed but its is still there.

The code I used when the user pressed the action button is:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Open in Safari"]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[self.webView.request URL]];
    }else if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Twitter"]){
        if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]){
            TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController   alloc] init];
            [tweetSheet addURL:[self.webView.request URL]];
            tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result){
                if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled){
                    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                }
            };
            [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
        }else {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twitter error" message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Twitter account setup" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem or is it a bug of the simulator?

P.S.: My app is a tabbar app and this code is called from one of of the view controller of the tab bar.

Comment: After updating the Xcode and iOS SDK to the latest version, it is now working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm having this same problem on the actual device. It turns out this is a bug in Apple's SDK for `TWTweetComposeViewController`.

See the bug report here on OpenRadar: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1484405.

> When a completionHandler block is added to
>   TWTweetComposeViewController, the completion handler needs to call
>   -[UIViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:], even though the view for the tweet composer dismisses itself with its cancel or
>   send buttons. Failure to do so causes touch events to not reach the
>   view that spawned the tweet composer.

Just thought I'd add how I'm doing things, even though this is not correctly following memory guidelines, it's a workaround:

```
[compose setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result){

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if(self.delegate != nil)
        {
            if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone)
            {
                [self.delegate twitterOperation:TETwitterOperationTweet
                          completedSuccessfully:YES
                             withResponseString:@"Tweet Successful"];
            }
            else if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
            {
                [self.delegate twitterOperation:TETwitterOperationTweet
                          completedSuccessfully:NO
                             withResponseString:@"Tweet Cancelled"];
            }
        }

        // Dismiss per Apple's Twitter example
        [self.shownInViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES 
                                                       completion:nil];

        // Yuck. But it's necessary.
        [compose release];
    });
```

Comment: After updating the Xcode and iOS SDK to the latest version, it is now working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Apparently, this is still needed as of iOS 6.1. Without `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` a second press on Cancel is needed to dismiss the `TWTweetComposeViewController`.

Comment: @OrtwinGentz I've since abandoned using `TWTweetComposeViewController` as it's now deprecated in iOS 6.0+. Instead I'm using the new Social Framework: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html